# Creating a dropdown button with just HTML & CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to create a button with a dropdown menu with just HTML & CSS?

```
<a id="TakeAction">Take Action</a>

<ul id="actions">
  <li>action 1</li>
  <li>action 2</li>
   ...
</ul>
```

When the link is clicked (hover is fine too, but click is preferred), I want ul#actions to show, where I can then chose my action.  I tried to do something like this, but the menu (ul#actions) disappears when the cursor moves out of the button.

```
ul#actions
{
    display:none;
}
#TakeAction:hover + ul#actions
{
    display: block;
}
```

Do I need javascript/jquery to do something like this?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're going for, but try this:

#TakeAction:hover + ul#actions, ul#actions:hover

Comment: take a look at http://cssmenumaker.com/ or http://www.cssmenubuilder.com/home or http://purecssmenu.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try enclose it all in a div and put the hover on that div:

HTML:

```
<div class="actions">
  <a id="TakeAction">Take Action</a>
  <ul id="actions">
    <li>action 1</li>
    <li>action 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul#actions
{
    display:none;
}
.actions:hover ul#actions
{
    display: block;
}
```

On hover: http://jsfiddle.net/gpf5n/

On click: http://jsfiddle.net/5p2SQ/

Comment: Thank you.  Is there anyway to change it to onclick rather than hover?

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for however, there's an issue with the jsFiddle code if you could help with that...the menu stays open even after I click outside it.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use Javascript?

Comment: A little bit of js is fine.  I saw a lot of jquery and js solutions online, and didn't want to deal with all that code.  But a little bit is fine...

Answer (score 2):

You can just use HTML Select Tag.

Here is my solution. [Fiddle: Dropdown button with CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/CaeGX/1/)

html

```
<select name='takeation'>
  <option class='head'>Select Action</option>
  <option value='Action 1'>Action 1</option>
  <option value='Action 2'>Action 2</option>
  <option value='Action 3'>Action 3</option>
</select>
```

css

```
option.head {
  selected:selected;
  display:none;
  disabled:disabled;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Why are you styling inline? You should be using CSS as that is what the question is asking; "Can this be done with HTML & CSS". Also inline styling is pretty much a no-no, except for when you build HTML emails.

Comment: Interesting way to hide the placeholder item.