# Is it possible to show a drop down on click only using CSS?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Has anybody tried making or seen a drop-down menu with only CSS, no javascript.

So **clicking** a toggle will show the drop-down (not hovering), and then the drop-down will hide on mouseleave.

I thought it may be possible using combinations of :hover and :active sates but I was unable to make it work.

I know this can easily be achieved with javascript, but I would like it to work with purely CSS.

Thanks

Edit: There are many examples of dropdowns triggered by :hover, I have yet to see an example of a css dropdown triggered by a **CLICK**.

Comment: Your commenters are trying to indicate that your question is too vague for SO's format. Google would have been a better approach.

Comment: Searching for "css only dropdown menu" will yield several examples

Comment: I'm sorry i was unclear about a specific detail which makes this different, i'll make and edit. The drop down must be triggered by a click, and hidden by mouse leave. I think this makes this question a bit more unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have it working! I'm not sure if this is the best solution possible, but it seems to work pretty well.

I used an :active handler to show the hidden menu, which is positioned on top of the button, allowing you to continue showing the menu with a :hover handler.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alsweeet/ycYg7/

HTML:

```
<div id="dd">
    <a href="#" id="button">Select Language</a>
    <ul>
        <li>English</li>
        <li>French</li>
        <li>German</li>
        <li>Spanish</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul{
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top: -55px;
    padding: 55px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul:hover{
    display: block; 
}

li{
    background: #ddd;
    padding: 10px;
    list-style: none;.
}

li:hover{ 
    background: #eee;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#button{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ccc;
    color: white;
}

#dd{
    display: inline-block;
}

#dd:active ul{
    display: block;
} 

#dd:aactive ul:hover{
    display: block;
}

#dd:active #button{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ccc;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great fiddle I have from a previous SO question.

The real magic is behind this line of `css`,

```
[type=radio]:checked ~ .content {
   z-index: 1;
}
```

This is adding a `z-index` of 1 when the corresponding radio button is clicked. Since the body underneath is gaining a z-index over the others it makes the section active.

**This is not a drop-down, I am providing a working example and it is up to you to make your situation. :}**

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/UbF9a/)

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/UbF9a/1/) I modified to show how you can show/hide on click with only css.

```
[type=radio]:checked ~ .content {
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: This looks very promising! i'm having a go with it now, trying to manipulate it into a drop-down menu that will hide on the hover off.

Comment: That is a good point to take into consideration of hiding it once unclicked. I'll see if there is a good article about them.

Comment: Here is a good question I found about this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452079/creating-a-dropdown-button-with-just-html-css. The best option I can think of is have 2 radio buttons. One for active and on to hide the menu.